# Web-kit, Css Clip forcing scrollbar

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have a large sprite image with a link around it, the link has a property of parent and the image a property of child.

I am using the **css clip** technique to pull a particular piece of the image. However, in my **chrome browser** even though I am **positioning** my child element **absolute** and giving it an **overflow** of **hidden** it is causing the **browser** to have **vertical/horizontal scrollbar.**

```
.parent{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;

}
.child {
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -154px;
    clip: rect(152px, 296px, 234px, 0px);
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Usage: 
`<a href="/" class="parent"> <img src="largeImage.png" class="child" /> </a>`

Works fine in firefox and Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: I tested your code with a online image and I don't see any horizontal scrollbar with chrome. check here http://jsbin.com/iguko

Comment: Shrink your browser to less then your actual real image size, you have a vertical scroll bar without even shrinking it.

Answer (score 2):

The `overflow` property must be set to `hidden` on the parent element in order to hide the overflowing portion content of its child elements.

(Aside: `overflow` affects block container elements; I'm not sure what if anything it's supposed to do on other elements.  See here for details: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow-clipping )

Your CSS, updated:

```
.parent{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
    border: 0;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -154px;
    clip: rect(152px, 296px, 234px, 0px);
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8TUnR/ didn't work right away for me; I had to position the parent as in (**working fiddle**) http://jsfiddle.net/8TUnR/1/ (and set a size to the latter as its only child is out of the flow). And... back to Firefox ^^